# how to run EJB 3 app on Jboss application server

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

While running the application i do not able to set the jndi.properties and log4j.properties

Actually i have to se the following properities but I do not know where to write these code in a file or somewhere else. If in file what will be the file extension and file name and where to keep it in application.

*jndi.properties:*

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
java.naming.provider.url=localhost:1099
```

*log4j.properties:*

```
# Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=- %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the default JBoss JNDI properties in jboss\server\default\conf\jndi.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you want to do or which Jboss version you use. But for the log4j options in Jboss 4.2.3 go to:
jboss\server\default\conf\jboss-log4j.xml